# clang-format: always break EACH PARAMETER if don't fit

Tags: clang, clang-format

```
// Try this first, ref 1:
SomeCall(aaa, bbb, ccc);

// If doesn't fit do this, ref 2:
SomeCall(aaa,
         bbb,
         ccc);

// Don't do, ref 3:
SomeCall(
    aaa, bbb, ccc);
```

I find that currently the only way to automatically break after each parameter (ref 2) is if the  option on ref 3 doesn't fit. I would like do be ref 2 even if ref 3 would fit. I use clang 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 9999
```

Basically set the Penalty value incredibly high